# How to use variables defined in an if statement outside of it

Tags: java

I have been trying to make a calculator and when I define variables inside an `if` statement it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       BlockNum cannot be resolved to a variable
>       at firsttry.Main.main(Main.java:57)

Now I know that you have to define variables outside of `if` statements, because of the variable scope, but when I try to do that like so:

```
package firsttry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int BlockNum;
        BlockNum = 1;
```

I get the error of:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Duplicate local variable BlockNum
>       at firsttry.Main.main(Main.java:36)

So how exactly would I fix this problem? From what I have read the only solution for that problem with the variable scope is to define the variable outside of the `if` statement, but it doesnt seem to work for me?

My full code:

```
package firsttry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int BlockNum;
        BlockNum = 1;
        csv bGather = new csv();
        ToolName atool = new ToolName();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Welcoming Message
        System.out.println("Welcome to Minecraft Build/excavate calculator"
            + "\nIts suggested you use tools that are suitable for the block"
            + "\nthat you are breaking as its much faster"
            + "");

        //GATHERES USER VARIABLES
        System.out.println("What block are you gathering? (use minecraft block ids)");
        String block = input.next();

        System.out.println("What tool are you using , 1 for using hand and up to 4 for diamond");
        int tool = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter the dimensions of the area you are excavating"
            + "or just the exact block number"
            + "1 for dimensions "
            + "2 for exact number");
        int TypeOfSelection = input.nextInt();
        if (TypeOfSelection == 1) {
            System.out.println("Height of the area");
            int Height = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("length of the area");
            int length = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("width of the area");
            int width = input.nextInt();
        } else if (TypeOfSelection == 2) {
            System.out.println("Exact amount of blocks");
            int BlockNum = input.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERRORRRR");
        }

        //CSV FILE STUF
        String ToolName = atool.NameOfTool(tool);
        String blockname = bGather.name(block);

        double blockbreak = bGather.speed(tool,block);
        input.close();

        //Overall calculations
        if (TypeOfSelection == 2) {
            System.out.println(BlockNum);
        }

        System.out.println("You are gatherering " + blockname + " using a " +       ToolName + " \nand it will take you " + blockbreak + " Seconds per block");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error clearly says on which line is the duplicate variable declaration. So why don't to refer to that line and figure out.

Comment: I know where the error is i just dont know how to fix it , if i remove the varaible outside of the if statement i get the variable scope error but if i keep it i get a duplicate error

Comment: Remove the int part on the second declaration Hope that works

Comment: ah that seems to fix it :) thanks for the help , i was just being stupid :P

Comment: No problems and glad it help brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (TypeOfSelection == 2){
        System.out.println("Exact amount of blocks");
        int BlockNum = input.nextInt();
}
```

If `int BlockNum` is the same variable as variable which you declared at the top, remove the `int` part.

```
else if (TypeOfSelection == 2){
    System.out.println("Exact amount of blocks");
    BlockNum = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
}else if (TypeOfSelection == 2){
            System.out.println("Exact amount of blocks");
            int BlockNum = input.nextInt();
        }
```

In above snippet, `BlockNum` is getting clash with the one in the following code:

```
int BlockNum;
BlockNum = 1;
```

Because, inside `if`, it sees that variable with the same name is already defined,

Solution:

Change name of the variable  in either of the case(e.g., use 
`int BlockNum1 = input.nextInt();`) .

Answer (score 0):

you were redeclaring a variable with the same name BlockNum.

if you are referring to the same variable outside the if then just call

```
}else if (TypeOfSelection == 2){
        System.out.println("Exact amount of blocks");
         BlockNum = input.nextInt();
    }
```

if you are not referring to the same variable you can rename one of the variable like

```
  }else if (TypeOfSelection == 2){
            System.out.println("Exact amount of blocks");
             int internalBlockNum = input.nextInt();
        }
```

you cannot create multiple variable in a method with  the same name.